# How do i extract specific lines recursively from a file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to extract specific lines from a file within some special quotes, for example I have functions like this in a file,

```
void VR_function1(xxx,yyy);
void VR_function2(xxx,yyy);
void VR_function3(xxx,yyy);
```

and I want to extract only

```
VR_function1
VR_function2
VR_function3
```

Assign each line to an array and process it later, and count the number of lines extracted.

Thanks in advance if someone can help me out with this one.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to extract the token you're looking for. But what platform or environment are you using? Is this a UNIX shell? Microsoft Windows? Are you using a specific programming language? In UNIX, you can use standard command-line tools like `grep`, `sed`, and `awk` to filter and parse your input.

Comment: You want specific lines, but your example shows every line.  The exact makeup of the file is important because the character set used and poison characters can break generic code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work!

```
FIND /C /N "VR_function" C:\filepath
```

you put the filepath of the file, or if its in the same folder, just type the name and extention

the /C displays the count of lines with the string

the /N displaysthe line numbers with the displayed lines

Comment: Thanks for the reply Csharper